# How to deploy a function on GCP with Cloud Build?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml

I have created a Cloud Function called `pupetter-e2e` with a trigger on changes to a bucket storage, called homepage. I want to deploy updates to the function with the following `cloudbuild.yaml`:

```yaml
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args:
  - functions
  - deploy
  - pupetter-e2e
  - --source=.
  - --trigger-bucket homepage
```

(trigger described: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying/filesystem)

or alternatively:

```yaml
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args:
  - functions
  - deploy
  - pupetter-e2e
  - --source=.
  - --trigger-resource hjemmeside  
  - --trigger-event google.storage.object.finalize
```

(as described as https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage)
sadly, I get

> ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) unrecognized arguments: --trigger-bucket hjemmeside (did you mean '--trigger-bucket'?) or
> --trigger-resource hjemmeside (did you mean --trigger-resource?)

I have attempted to use `--trigger-bucket`, but can not get it to work properly. Could someone please help me by correcting the mistake in my `cloudbuild.yaml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 solution to solve this (and even more, but 2 is already good). Firstly, Space aren't accepted in the args list, so:

- Replace the space by an equal.

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args:
  - functions
  - deploy
  - pupetter-e2e
  - --source=.
  - --trigger-bucket=homepage
```

- Put the param value in a new ARGS value (new line)

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args:
  - functions
  - deploy
  - pupetter-e2e
  - --source=.
  - --trigger-bucket 
  - homepage
```